# Python-TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, exception

I have the following class and function in my program:

```
class RaiseAndTurnOff(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value, r1):
        self.value = value
        r1.turn_off_gracefully()
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

def assert_state(self, state):
    if not(self.link.is_in_state(state)):
        raise RaiseAndTurnOff("Sanity check error: Link should be %s, but it is not! please check the log file reports. Exiting script" % state, self, self.params)
```

As you can see I send 3 arguments. For some reason I got the following error:

```
File "qalib.py", line 103, in assert_state
    raise RaiseAndTurnOff("Sanity check error: Link should be %s, but it is not! please check the log file reports. Exiting script" % state, self, self.params)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Your exception and posted code do not match. Did you perhaps already correct the error but forgot to restart the Python interpreter?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters- but the self og the RaiseAndTurnOff is different from the self I send from the function

Comment: Yes, that's indeed different. What are you trying to do then, why do you want to pass in a different `self`? You can't do that *and* create an instance of `RaiseAndTurnOff` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Python binds methods to an instance for you, which means that the `self` argument is provided for you. You don't need to pass it in yourself.

Drop the first argument to `RaiseAndTurnOff`:

```
raise RaiseAndTurnOff("Sanity check error: Link should be %s, but it is not! please check the log file reports. Exiting script" % state, self.params)
```

You may want to break that long string into chucks for readibility:

```
raise RaiseAndTurnOff(
    "Sanity check error: Link should be %s, but it is not! "
    "please check the log file reports. Exiting script" % state,
    self.params)
```

Python automatically joins consecutive string literals in a logical line.

I must point out that the constructor of an `Exception` subclass sounds like the wrong location to 'turn off' something. It'd be far better if the exception could be created without side-effects; call `self.params.turn_off_gracefully()` separately before raising the exception (which would be renamed):

```
self.params.turn_off_gracefully()
raise SanityException(
    "Sanity check error: Link should be %s, but it is not! "
    "please check the log file reports. Exiting script" % state)
```

You could put those two lines into a function perhaps, then call that instead.